# Sort objects quickly based on specified order of their property names

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I have a List that holds objects of this type

```
class Element 
{
     String description; 
     ...
}
```

These objects are contained in a list.

```
List<Element> elements = ...
```

This list is to be sorted in ascending order based on the `description` property of the `Element` objects.

The Element objects can have only standard descriptions, which need to be sorted based on a specified order -

```
descE
descA
descK
descB
descF
...
```

In order to make this sorting quick, my current plan is as follows -

Use a `Comparator<Element>`, so that I can use the `Collections.sort(list,comparator)` function. Store the standard descriptions in a HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> descriptionOrder = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
descriptionOrder.put("descE", 0);
descriptionOrder.put("descA", 100);
descriptionOrder.put("descK", 200);
descriptionOrder.put("descB", 300);
descriptionOrder.put("descF", 400);
```

I added a buffer of 100 in case more descriptions need to be added later in between two elements.

```
public int compare(Element a, Element b)
 {
       int valueForA = descriptionOrder.get(a.getDescription());
       int valueForB = descriptionOrder.get(b.getDescription());

       return (valueForA - valueForB); 
 }
```

My question is, is there a faster or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How are you planning to populate the order?

Comment: You mean the HashMap? Manually, in the code.

Comment: Roughly how many items are going to be in your collection? If it's a small number, speed will most likely not be important.

Comment: @MartinCarney, in my case, the items will not be more than 30 or 40, but suppose there are more than that, how can this be made more efficient?

Comment: However, it may be that there will be many lists with a small number of items.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to micro-optimize, which is almost never worthwhile. I could just be misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish, though.

Comment: @MartinCarney, I think you're right. Why don't you make this an answer? I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have is ok.

However you might want to consider that a List can hold nulls and you might want to handle nulls  in your compare method. That way you can be sure how the comparison caters to null values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to create a separaate Comparator class for defining the comparaisions betoween objects of Element class then you can use Collections.sort for sorting your Arraylist.

```
  Comparator<Elements> comparator = new ElementsComparator<Elements>();
  Collections.sort (elements, comparator);
```

here is the link for the same : [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 0):

Since your key is a string, you could use a TreeMap. This would sort by key name in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you absolutely require it that the description be a String type.

You could always have your classes as follows.

```
class Description implements Comparable<Description> {
   private final String name;
   private final int precedence;

   // rest of the Code

}

class Element implements Comparable<Element> {
   private Description desc;
   // rest of the code.
}
```